# Elasticsearch - getting data from "_doc" request without the id

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm developing a sample app using Elasticsearch. I'm fairly new to it, and have been using SQL databases for most of my years as a programmer, and I came to find out Elasticsearch is in a different world.

From my app, my goal is to retrieve some articles, based on the user(s) that worked on it.

My question is, when using a `_doc` request, for instance `localhost:9200/publications/_doc/1`, is there any way I can fetch data with something other than the id, being `1` in this case ?

For instance, if I have an article mapping with a nested field of authors (basically a list of `"name": "keyword"`, can I somehow fetch an article X based on the fact that author U is in the list of authors ?

I spent pretty much all day looking for an answer on the official Elasticsearch documentation, and I couldn't find anything to answer that question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is needed here is a query. The below is a get request and not a query.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XGET 127.0.0.1:9200/shakespeare/_doc/0?pretty
```

By this we get the record. Here shakespeare is the index. Note Http verb is GET.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/shakespeare/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id": "0"
    }
  }
}'
```

Now we have a query. Note the Http verb is POST. Here I get the document with id 0.

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "shakespeare",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "0",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "type" : "act",
          "line_id" : 1,
          "play_name" : "Henry IV",
          "speech_number" : "",
          "line_number" : "",
          "speaker" : "",
          "text_entry" : "ACT I"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When have a query, we can query for specific records and also specific fields as follows. In the below query, we have queried for a specfic record, with id 0, and also specified that I need only fields type, line_id etc.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/shakespeare/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id": "0"
    }
  },
  "fields": ["type", "line_id", "text_entry", "play_name"]
}'
```

Note there is _source included in the response below.

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "shakespeare",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "0",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "type" : "act",
          "line_id" : 1,
          "play_name" : "Henry IV",
          "speech_number" : "",
          "line_number" : "",
          "speaker" : "",
          "text_entry" : "ACT I"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "play_name" : [
            "Henry IV"
          ],
          "text_entry" : [
            "ACT I"
          ],
          "type" : [
            "act"
          ],
          "line_id" : [
            1
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Finally, if I want to omit the _source, then the query would be as follows, with "_source" = false.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/shakespeare/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id": "0"
    }
  },
  "fields": ["type", "line_id", "text_entry", "play_name"],
  "_source": false
}'
```